# "No module named specutils" although specutils installation went through

Tags: python, conda, astropy

I am trying to install the Specutils package.
I followed [these instructions](http://conda%20install%20-c%20astropy%20specutils) and typed the following command in my Anaconda Prompt terminal:

`conda install -c astropy specutils`

The installation went through. Typing `conda list` confirms that specutils 0.5.2 is installed.

However, trying to import specutils from Spyder does not work! I am getting a message stating that there is *No module named specutils*.

Any clue what I am doing wrong?

FYI, I am working from the "base" conda environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These problems are in most instances problems with the IDE. It does not pick up on the right Python environment that you installed stuff into. Verify this by running python from the command line and note the output of `import sys;print(sys.prefix)`. Compare that to the one you are getting from within Spyder.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, deets! Typing `print(sys.prefix)` in a python terminal reads: "C:\Users\Sheldon\Anaconda2". Doing the same in the Spyder IPython console returns "C:\Users\Sheldon\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2".

Comment: So ist two different Pythons. Make Spyder use the first one. Or use the second one to install the module.

Comment: Thanks, deets! I realized that I have two different versions of Spyder installed on my computer. The one that I can call from the Anaconda terminal has no problem importing the specutils module. Now I just need to figure out how to install specutils on the other version of Spyder... In any case, I will accept your answer since it helped me figure out what my problem was!